# Colab kernel restarts for unknown reasons

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, kernel, google-colaboratory

[image: Colab crash logs]
My colab kernel restarted itself for unknown reasons when I tried to plot my data with matplotlib plot (right before which, I had successfully plotted histograms for the same data). The colab gave a notification to check the runtime logs, which are as follows. I don't see any apparent reason why this happened.

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bDK9K-WMymHAiNcPq2CiXMoWW0J3KXxq

Comment: It happens when I run the cell with the last uncommented statement

Answer (score 0):

I just found out why it was happening. The colab runtime RAM was being consumed entirely while running through the last cell. It happened when I used the matplotlib plot, but when I used matplotlib histograms, it turned out just fine. Histograms are probably lighter when you have a high precision float values.
I repeated with multiple trials between the two methods, and got the same result every time.